# Multiline Jlabel with specific HTML tag

Tags: html, swing, label, jlabel

I want to add multi line to my Jlabel; I do it with help of HTML, but in some situation I have problem with it, the situation is that I use special tag property like dir="RTL" and ... . What should I do to solve this problem?

If I use:
 `jLabel1.setText("<html><center>John<br>2010/7/21 11:57:47 AM<br>In</center></html>");`
The label show :

```
        john   
2010/7/21 11:57:47 AM  
         In
```

But If I use :

```
jLabel1.setText("<html DIR=\"LTR\"><center>John<br>2010/7/21 11:57:47 AM<br>In</center></html>");
```

The label show:

```
<html DIR=\"LTR\"><center>John<br>2010/7/21 11:57:47 AM<br>In</center></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jLabel1.setText("<html DIR="LTR"><center>John<br>2010/7/21 11:57:47 AM<br>In</center></html>");
```

Needs to be

```
jLabel1.setText("<html DIR=\"LTR\"><center>John<br>2010/7/21 11:57:47 AM<br>In</center></html>");
```

That is, you need to escape double quotes inside a double quoted string. What you're doing at the moment is printing out `<html DIR=`, breaking the string, then printing `><center>John<br>2010/7/21 11:57:47 AM<br>In</center></html>`.

Comment: sorry man I I use DIR=\"LTR\" in my code otherwire it wouldn't compile I just write wrong here, I fix my question

Answer (score 1):

If you start your label text with `<html dir="ltr">`, it will not be an HTML label but a plain text label. The reason is that `java.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML#isHtmlString(String)` is very simple, its implementation is

```
public static boolean isHTMLString(String s) {
if (s != null) {
    if ((s.length() >= 6) && (s.charAt(0) == '<') && (s.charAt(5) == '>')) {
    String tag = s.substring(1,5);
    return tag.equalsIgnoreCase(propertyKey);
    }
}
return false;
}
```

so you can only use `<html>` or `<HTML>`, or interestingly also `<abcd>` or other four-letter words :-)

So in your case you would have to use `<html><span dir="ltr">Your text</span></html>`. However, the Swing HTML subsystem does not honor the `dir` attribute. You have to call

```
label.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
```

in order to change the component orientation for a label.

Comment: Tanx fot your answer it s userful,I use label.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT) before this solution but it didn't work.

Comment: LEFT_TO_RIGHT is standard for Western languages. Maybe you want to do RIGHT_TO_LEFT to see a change?

Comment: Yes I need RIGHT_TO_LEFT and in my real code I use rtl for better understanding I put the ltr code in stackoverflow sample.